# Publishing Multiple Shapefiles

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite

I'm using OpenGeo Suite 3.1.I have stored large number of shapefiles(100) in a store()Directory of spatial files.

How to Publish all the files at a time in geoserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also check out the "Import Data" option, available from the main menu. It allows you to batch import files from a directory. http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/3.1/dataadmin/importer/index.html

Comment: ok..I need for multiple shapefiles from multiple folders or directories..

Answer (score 2):

So you have created a store using the Directroy of spatial files (shapefiles) option?
I don't think there is a possibility in geoserver to publish all files from that store at once. All layers need to be created separately. This is to give you the possibility to enter the correct bounding boxes, styles, etc...

Comment: Is there any possibility with REST API?

Comment: I am not familiar with the REST API, but maybe this link is useful: [http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html].   But maybe you have seen this already?